# Limitations of playback by SoundEffectInstance (Cross platform)

Tags: audio, xna, xna-4.0, monogame, soundeffect

I am developing a game using MonoGame that uses SoundEffectInstance for in-game sound effects. What are the limitation on the different platforms with regard to the number of SoundEffect instances that can be created and most importanly that can be played simultaneously?

Are there limitations of how many SoundEffects (needed to create instances) can be loaded?

Relevant platforms are Windows 8 (Metro), Windows 7, Linux, OSX, X-Box 360, Android, iOS.

[Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.audio.soundeffectinstance.aspx) communicates that there is a limit of **300 sound effects** (instances that can be loaded or played simultaneously) and on Windows there seems to be **no limit**. However, information for other platforms seems to not be available.

Answer (score 1):

I've done a lot of XNA to MonoGame ports for: iOS, Android, Win8 Metro, PSM, Windows Phone.

SoundEffects and SoundEffectInstances work as expected on all platforms except for Android. You cannot use SoundEffectInstances for anything on Android. Once a sound fires you CANNOT stop or pause it. It will play to completion.

SoundEffects cut off after about ten seconds. If you plan on doing a MonoGame android port then keep this in mind. Personally I would avoid Android until the MonoGame team has implemented OpenAL.

Comment: Thank you for sharing that experience. This information is very useful. The question, however, was specifically about the limitations with regard to the number of sound effects that can be played simulataneously. Also, what do you use for sound on Android?